# beforeskip does not work with tabu

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, tabu

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc, version=last,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1cm, afterskip=.2cm]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1][1]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1][1]
\section{Three}
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{document}
```

produces following output:
[image]

This is correct and expected. But when using **tabu** (I am using *beforeskip=-10cm* on purpose):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc, version=last,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{showframe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10cm, afterskip=.2cm]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{longtabu} {l}
    A \\
\end{longtabu}
\section{Two}
\begin{longtabu} {l}
    B \\
\end{longtabu}
\section{Three}
\begin{longtabu} {l}
    C \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

I am getting following output:

[image]

This is not expected: the spacing before **section** is not *10cm*. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Tabu is buggy and unmaintained. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/. Don't expect help for it.

Comment: And what are the alternatives?

Comment: for your example longtable.

Comment: Mmmh... interestingly enough, I am getting the same problem by using **longtable** only. So, the problem does NOT seem to be **tabu** related. Should I open a new thread?

Comment: I didn't try to imply that your problem is related to tabu, but if tabu is involved many people don't try to debug a problem.

Comment: If the problem is not related to [`tabu`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabu), should this question be closed?